# DataTables initialization keywords different with official examples

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces, datatables

I'm new to DataTables due to new requirements of a project. I've started to learn it, but I'm confused about the inconsistency between the official site examples and the real usages.

Specifically, I wonder why the name of the options when initialize datatables could be always different between the official examples and practical use. For example, in official guides, initializing table with static data is demonstrated as follow:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    data: data
} );
```

However, after I realised this does not work. I searched in statckoverflow so I got the solution should be

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "aaData": data
});
```

So, why they maintain the gap. Is this because of some issues like the namespace? Also, if they always different, how could I know the correct keywords of those options?

I know that this question might be stupid, but I failed to find the answer for many hours. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hungarian notation `aaData` is used for jQuery DataTables 1.9. New camelCase naming convention `data` is used in jQuery DataTables 1.10+. Both are supported in jQuery DataTables 1.10+ to provide backward compatibility.

See [Converting parameter names for 1.10](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert) for more information.

Documentation for older 1.9 version is still available at http://legacy.datatables.net/

Comment: Thanks a lot. We are using a bootstrap template for our site. I've just checked the version they used that is 1.9.4. So your answer is quite accurate and the resource you provide is good guide to mapping the names. Thanks again.

Comment: @Christopher, documentation for older version is still available at http://legacy.datatables.net/